# Angular routing not navigating to another page

Tags: angular

```
    //Auth-routing.module.ts
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
    
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: LoginComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'invoice',
            loadChildren: () => import('../Invoice/Components/invoice.module').then(m => m.InvoiceModule)
          },
        ]
      }
    ];
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    })
    export class AuthRoutingModule {}


//login.component.ts
 login2() {
    this.router.navigate(['invoice']);
  }
```

after login2() function called, page is not redirecting to invoice page.
I have created Invoice module and after calling login2(), I want to redirect to Invoice page

Comment: Try  this.router.navigate(['/invoice']);

Answer (score 0):

Actually your Routes Configuration is a bit confusing.

```
        path: '',
        component: LoginComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'invoice',
            loadChildren: () => import('../Invoice/Components/invoice.module').then(m => m.InvoiceModule)
          },
        ]
```

this means you want to treat the invoice path to be child of login component.
that means whenever you want to reach invoice page Login page also will also be displayed.

This type of route is used when u want to display the parent page always.Ex: WHen you have set a Layout Component which will have navigation tabs.Which is to be shown in all child pages.Then u will write components as children of that parent layout component.

I dont think your routing is correct.

```
   {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
   path: 'invoice',
   loadChildren: () => import('../Invoice/Components/invoice.module').then(m => m.InvoiceModule)
   }
```

and your invoice routing module must be imported in invoice module.and path must be written in invoice routingmodule also.

```
   {
    path: '',
    component: InvoiceComponent
  },
```

Since your question is full clear.I will give you something more which may be helpful.

**`this.router.navigate(['invoice']);`** //This will route to **RELATIVE** path.Means if u are on Login page and if u route to invoice.ur routing address will be **`.../login/invoice`**.

**`this.router.navigate(['/invoice']);`** //This will route to **ABSOLUTE** path.Means if u are on Login page and if u route to invoice.ur routing address will be **`.../invoice`**.

I think this will be useful in your case.Since u want to route to /invoice and not /login/invoice.

this.router.navigateByUrl is also used depending on our needs.This will take only a **string** ,different to the later case ,which will take array of paths.

**navigateByUrl** it always will be **ABSOLUTE** paths.Also **external URLS** can be used here which will route outside our app.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the relative route

```
this.router.navigate(['invoice'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

check here for more detailed information:https://angular.io/guide/router#specifying-a-relative-route